# Disable a button based on three textbox fields

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I'm quite new to VB.net (and VS 2008), so I'm afraid my question might be basic, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have a winform with three textbox fields and a button. All textbox fields must be filled before the user can click the button to continue. To this end I would like to disable the button as long as there is at least one empty textbox.

If I had only one textbox field, it would be easy for me to do. In the `Textbox1_Leave` event I would check if `Textbox1.Text` is not empty and if so, set `Button1.Enabled = True`.
But what should I do if I have three textboxes? Have three event handlers, one for each textbox? Or is there a way I'm not familiar with?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddHandler Textbox1.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateInputs
AddHandler Textbox2.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateInputs
AddHandler Textbox3.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateInputs

Private Sub ValidateInputs(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    Button1.Enabled = Not (Textbox1.Text = String.Empty OrElse Textbox2.Text = String.Empty OrElse Textbox3.Text = String.Empty)
End Sub
```

And, even better, if these controls all have the same parent, and are the only textboxes in the parent (say, all nested in a groupbox), you can do it something like this:

```
For Each t As TextBox In GroupBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Textbox)
   AddHandler t.TextChanged, AddressOf ValidateInputs
Next t

Private Sub ValidateInputs(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e as EventArgs)
    Button1.Enabled = Not GropuBox1.Controls.OfType(Of Textbox).Any(Function(t) t.Text = String.Empty)
End Sub
```

Comment: And don't forget to set the Enabled property of the button to False as default (as I did... d'oh!). Thank you, your answer helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

Have a generic sub which checks the three text boxes which is called whenever any of them is left.

Effectively it would be

```
sub CheckBoxes
If (textbox1.text <> "") AND (textbox2.text <> "") AND (textbox3.text <> "") Then
    Button1.Enabled = True
else
    Button1.Enabled = False
End If
end sub
```

I apologise for this not being VBA syntax but the psuedo code should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that can check the status of all three textboxes and enable button1 if all three have text.

Create an event handler for all three text boxes that calls this method.

Edit: As a side note, you may want to use "Text Changed" event rather than "Leave" event, because focus on the third text box may not be lost if the very next thing they do after typing is click the button.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the varying controls [Validating](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Articles/ArticleTemplate.Aspx?ArticleID=1263) event and then adjust the enabled/disabled behavior of the button accordingly based on the successful validation of the controls.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating.aspx) explanation...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox5_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox5.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Or TextBox2.Text = "" Or TextBox3.Text = "" Or TextBox4.Text = "" Or TextBox5.Text = "" Then
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Else
            Button1.Enabled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: There are five TextBoxes and one Button in Form1. Button1 will be disabled if any one of the TextBoxes is empty